# Drag and drop games within an interactive app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to both Stack Overflow and javascript. I've been asked to create an app so that people can enjoy learning sciences. I've come up with questions and I've made them draggable, as far as I know. I'm getting stuck with making the answers droppable though.

I've searched for days now looking for some really simple javascript code that could help, but everything that people have posted, looks way too difficult for a beginner.

If anyone's got any simple javascript code that could help my app work, or any helpful tips, then that would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried uploading my code, but it's not allowing me to do so. I've managed to upload it to JSFiddle and here's the link -

```
jsfiddle.net/0t9h82vs/ - This just needs to be copied into your URL bar
```

Kind regards and thanks for you help!

Comment: Adding your code is surely a good idea. It makes us able to understand what exactly you're trying to do and tell you what's wrong as well. Please edit your question with any relevant code you have.

Comment: I recommend adding your code to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that it doesn't clutter up your question. You could also use the default code snippet utility, and check the "hide by default" box.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Include the relevant code to a specific problem you're having only, not the whole program.

Comment: I've managed to use JSFiddle to add my code in::

http://jsfiddle.net/0t9h82vs/

Comment: I also don't understand why it's not working on jsfiddle. When I open it on my computer, it seems to be working

Comment: I could help you one on one.

Answer (score 1):

I made a very simplified version of what you want, here is how you can do it:
The simple HTML:

```
<div class="drag">Drag Me!</div>
<div class="drop">Drop Here!</div>
```

First of all, we start by declaring the `var`:

```
var activeE, clicking=false;
```

Then, add the `mousedown` event for `.drag`:

```
$('.drag').mousedown(function(){
        activeE=this;//This sets the active element to this
        $(this).addClass('dragActive');//Adds the CSS class used
        clicking=true;//Sets the clicking variable to true
        $('body').addClass('noselect');//Not necessary, it just stops you from selecting text while dragging
    });
```

Next, you set the document `mouseup` function, to reset all the variables when the element is dropped:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clicking=false;//Not that much explaining needed, it just resets everything
    $('.dragActive').removeClass('dragActive');
    activeE=null;
    $('body').removeClass('noselect');
});
```

Then, we add a little bit of code so the user can see the element dragging:

```
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       if(clicking==true){
         var x = e.clientX,y = e.clientY;//jQuery methods, finds the cursors position.
         $('.drag').css({top:(y-($('.drag').height()/2)), left:(x-($('.drag').width()/2))});//And this changes the `activeE`'s position in mouse move.
        }
    });
```

And then, the drop function. very simple, it justs appends `activeE` to `.drop`:

```
$('.drop').mouseup(function(){
    clicking=false;//again, resets.
    $(this).append(activeE);//and appends
    $('.dragActive').removeClass('dragActive');
    $('body').removeClass('noselect');
});
```

And then, a little CSS to finish it off:

```
.dragActive{
    pointer-events:none;
    position:absolute;
}
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor:move;
}
```

And TADA! all finished!

### Complete JS:

```
$(function(){
    var activeE, clicking=false;
    $('.drag').mousedown(function(){
        activeE=this;
        $(this).addClass('dragActive');
        clicking=true;
        $('body').addClass('noselect');
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        clicking=false;
        $('.dragActive').removeClass('dragActive');
        activeE=null;
        $('body').removeClass('noselect');
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
   if(clicking==true){
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    $('.drag').css({top:(y-($('.drag').height()/2)), left:(x-($('.drag').width()/2))});
    }
    });
    $('.drop').mouseup(function(){
        clicking=false;
        $(this).append(activeE);
        $('.dragActive').removeClass('dragActive');
        $('body').removeClass('noselect');
    });
});
```

### And CSS:

```
    .drag{
    background:pink;
        padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:100px;
    cursor:move;
}
.dragActive{
    pointer-events:none;
    position:absolute;
}
.drop{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor:move;
}
```

## [Don't Forget The JSFiddle!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/9L0wt2y1/3/)

Comment: I've just tried using that, but I'm having a few problems with that still.

i'm also finding the whole javascript really really complicated

Comment: @c3367371 for what you are trying to do, that will be about as simplified as it gets, if you are coding it yourself and not using a library. :D What are you having problems with?

Comment: That looks so complicated. I've been using javascript for the past couple of weeks now, and I still don't understand what every little peice of javascript means.

And I tried making a new document and tried using your code, but I'm not entirely sure why it wasn't working

Comment: @c3367371 did you add the jQuery Library? what errors is it throwing in the console?

Comment: I think so. Is that the same as online link to the local version of jquery? Because if so, my tutor added it in.

And as far as i know, my tutor created the necessary starting pages, all with the current html, css and javascript that he thought would be necessary

Comment: @c3367371 can you make a jsfiddle with all the coding, so i can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/0t9h82vs/ - That's my work as it currently stands. You just need to copy that link into your url. Does it work for you? Because it won't work online for me. If you copy all the text into separate html, css and js documents, it should work.

What i'm trying to do is, making each separate div on the left hand side draggable, which I think I've done, and I'm trying to make the divs on the right hand side droppable, but I don't understand how to do that

Comment: @c3367371you have to add jquery to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnjdogap/

Comment: I think I have in the "Other pages" section - where I've mentioned "My jquery starts from here"?

I don't know what sort of code I need to add in, in order for the right divs to be droppable and to allow all of the left divs to be dropped onto the right divs =/

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom J Query library like this one.

[http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

This is the implementation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've actually had a look at that ^^ but i'm not looking for moving boxes around. I know I can change it, but I'm not sure how to do that tbh

Comment: I didn't down vote anything. I don't even know how to use this site properly. Just made an account last night

Answer (score 0):

```
    function dragDiv(event, div){
      // Drag set to false
      var drag = false;
      // Mouse down event listener
      div.addEventListener("mousedown", function( event ) {   
        // If mouse is down, drag is set to true
        drag = true;
        // Gets location of the div
        var top = event.clientY - div.style.top;
        var left = event.clientX - div.style.left;

        // Adds mouse move event listener to the body
        document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function( event ) { 
          // If mouse is down
          if(drag){
            // Move the div with mouse
            div.style.top = event.clientY - top;
            div.style.left = event.clientX - left;
          }
        }, false);
        // Add mouse up event listener
        div.addEventListener("mouseup", function( event ) {   
          // If mouse is released, drag is set to false
          drag = false;
        }, false);
      }, false);
    };
```

Comment: Is there any other simpler code for this^^?

Comment: I don't really think so? I think it is a catch all method. You pick the div you want to move then relative to the body (i.e, if you move your mouse anywhere on the screen) it will move the div.

Comment: What do you mean by, you pick the div you want to move, then relative to the body?